# Different iOS Direct Update Dialog Buttons from same code from SVN with two different build processes (WL Studio / Jenkins Xcode)?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

We are seeing a strange behavior in our iOS part of the App:

We are using a Jenkins Build Server with an XCode plugin to compile the app on the command line

At first we had an SVN ignore on the iPhone "native" folder in our SVN. So all was taken from common and the whole native project was generated by the worklight Ant scripts on the Jenkins server. This was then compiled by the xcode on jenkins and the App worked fine with Direct Update - the Dialog had a "UPDATE" and a "EXIT" button, both buttons worked as intended.

Then we added a CustomWebView to our project and had to include the native folder into the SVN. We tried to SVN.ignore all generated files and the build processes in Worklight Studio and on the Jenkins xcode server work both fine.
We did not change any of the generated code except we added two classes:

```
WebViewOverlayPlugin.h
WebViewOverlayPlugin.m
```

and added the plugin to the config.xml:

```
<plugin name="WebViewOverlayPlugin" value="WebViewOverlayPlugin"/>
```

BUT:

- when we compile the same SVN code in the Worklight Studio, we have an iPhone app that has a Direct Update dialog with only the "UPDATE" button across the whole dialog. There is no "EXIT" button anymore at all.
- when we compile the same SVN on the Jenkins Xcode server, we have an iPhone app that has a Direct Update dialog with an "UPDATE" and an "EXIT" button but the "EXIT" button does not work as intended  - when pressing it, the app stays open and the dialog closes, so the user can continue to use the old version of the app without updating. The "UPDATE" button works and updates the App.

So my question is, what build setting, generated files or configuration etc. could have any influence on the behavior of the Direct Update dialog. Since we use the exact same SVN source it has to have something to do with something generated, or with some configuration.

Is anything around such a strange behavior known?

Is it known that one can "configure" the Direct Update dialog to have only an "UPDATE" button with no "EXIT"?

Thank you all for any help or hint where we could look to further investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention your Worklight version, but starting with Worklight 5.0.6.x:

1. The Direct Update dialog will feature only 1 button - Update. The  Exit button was removed. 
   This was done in order to be inline with Apple's App Store submission guidelines.
2. And more in general, the WL.App.close API method was rendered "non functional", because as per Apple's guidelines, it is the user that should be given the control on exiting the application and not the application to do so. Think of it as an "OK" button instead of "Exit".

That said, you are not supposed to see an Exit button to begin with. But again, I do not know what is your Worklight version and what exactly is your build setup to understand what is going on there that does this sort of mixing.

You are not supposed to be able to "configure" anything in Direct Update. It is non-configurable in this respect.

As for why you have 2 buttons when building with Worklight Studio, but 1 button after adding the WebOverlayPlugin, it is interesting. Is there a chance the app is of a lower Worklight version and you are now building it with a newer version of Worklight, containing the changes made, as described above?

Comment: Thank you for your response ... we actually have a version "problem" meaning that we started off with Eclipse Plugin 5.0.6100.20130416015 but set up our Jenkins build server with files from IBM Installation Manager Worklight Studio IWSO506-I20130307_1415 ... then we updated the Eclipse Plugin to to 5.0.6100.201307241533 for the iOS7 update and did not update the Jenkins server yet. Do you think this could have been the problem? Are the IWSO506-I20130307_1415 and 5.0.6100.20130416015 different versions that have different EXIT button functionality?

Comment: Doubtful, but maybe... sync the versions, see how it goes. But do note that the expected behavior is to not have an exit button in your Direct Update dialog AFAIK. If you'll check with a blank new app and trigger a DU, you should not see that button. If you do, then I guess I got confused(!).